# Axon no Handler Found for query when returning Response with Generic

Tags: kotlin, axon

We are having issues when our **Axon QueryHandler** is returning a Class with a Generic parameter like `QueryResult<T>`. 
For example:

```
class QueryResult<T>(val values: List<T>, val status: Status,
                                 var text: String? = null) : Serializable {
...
}
```

And our query handler:

```
@QueryHandler
    fun handle(query: SomeQuery): QueryResult<String>{
```

Axon is giving us the following message:

> NoHandlerForQueryException: No handler found for [SomeQuery] with
>   response type [InstanceResponseType{class QueryResult}]

Is using Generics allowed in QueryHandlers or do we have to call queryGateway in some specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axon will only resolve generics for the following return types:

- `Collection`s
- `Future`s
- `Optional`s

I believe your desired query response would require a new implementation of the `ResponeType` interface, which will do even further inspection upon the available generics.

Short answer? What you're trying to do isn't possible at the moment.

The [documentation](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/query-handling/handling-queries#supported-single-instance-return-values) is relative short on this, but still clear I think. If you disagree on that, you're free to provide a [pull request](https://github.com/AxonIQ/reference-guide/issues) or open up an issue to request for clarity on the matter.